# how to link the fmod library in visual studio

Tags: c++, windows, resources

I am just a beginner at windows programming and was reading a tutorial about it. 
It said something about resources for menu creation.

I am working in visual studio 2010 and would like to know how to create these resources (the turorial said something about adding them to the compiler which i could not understand) for simple things like menu bar creation.

Please help me.(Please keep in mind that I am a beginner therfore explain in detail if possible.)

Comment: Your title has absolutely nothing to do with your question -- what is it that you actually want to know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To actually use the additional functionality you have to include the header and specify the directory where it is contained so the project can find the file

right click on project->properties
C\C++->general tab
the top element is Additional Include Directories - click the down arrow and specify the path to the header file

For your application to use the functionality you have to link with the lib

right click on project->properties
Linker->general tab

The 9th element from the top is Additional Lib Directories

& specify the path to the accompanying lib file

NOTE that the dll that corresponds (if dynamically linked) must be either in the system path or in the working directory  of your application

under the linker -> input tab

you'll want to specify the name of the .lib file to load (the same as the file contained within the path you specify to link with with)

Alternatively - if the you'd like to make a project depend on another project within the same solution

right click the project->properties
the top tab is Common Properties
within that tab click the button "Add New Reference" and select the project